# How to set selected item of HTML select element before render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I know how to set selected item of select element using jquery, like this:

```
$('select#someId').val(someValue);
```

But, it only works after the select element is rendered. My question is can we set selected item of HTML select element before rendering process?

Comment: how is the `select#someId` element created?

Comment: @ArunPJohny : I created `select#someId` using jquery, `$(document.createElement('select')).attr('id', 'someId')`

Comment: how is the options added? please share the complete code related to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating the select element using jQuery, you can use the reference returned by the creation code to set the value.

When you use and id selector as used by you, it will only look up in the existing dom tree to find the element reference.

```
var sel = $(document.createElement('select')).attr('id', 'someId');
//add options
sel.val(someValue);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bXk7f/)

Comment: Thanks. I try your solution and it works. I just don't know why my original code doesn't work when I use `$(sel).val(someValue)`